# Rendering ViewComponent returns HTML 500 Error

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-viewcomponent

I have a very simple solution based on MVC 6.

ViewComponent ->  /ViewComponents/PriorityListViewComponent.cs

```
public class PriorityListViewComponent : ViewComponent
{
    public IViewComponentResult Invoke(int maxPriority)
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

"Partial" View /Views/Components/PriorityList/Default.cshtml

```
Empty view
```

View /Views/Shared/Index.cshtml

```
@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/BaseView.cshtml";
 }
 @Component.Invoke("PriorityList", 1)
```

The above returns an HTTP 500 error, and i can't figure out why. I think all rules regarding paths are being helt.

Answer (score 3):

Figured out that error was due to wrong mapping of Views the correct directory should have been

```
View /Views/Shared/Components/PriorityList/Default.cshtml
```